# A person who can speak on any topic

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, obscure-terms

This is a person who can talk about any topic related to any field; for example,  medical, politics, history, engineering, etc. and not just in a boasting way, this person actually posses knowledge in these fields mainly by reading books, magazines etc. Also, this word is not used in a sarcastic way, it's actually a deferential word.

The person is not necessary to posses 'deep knowledge' of the subject, just enough to converse with people.

Comment: conversationalist, or raconteur (strong tinge towards teller of colorful anecdotes ) are a couple situational words for types of people who easily talk or take the stage.  (might not be what you're angling towards though)

Answer (score 2):

> **polymath**
>
> noun
>
> 1. a person of great learning in several fields of study; polyhistor.
>
> [[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/polymath)]

Comment: A backwards-check for 'polymath' shows that this is not original.